# What's the added value in the sophisticated use of C++ templates advocated by Alexandrescu and others?

Tags: c++

In general terms, what's the added value in using the techniques described in the iconic book "Modern C++ Design"?  Is it simply the ability to write reusable code that's easily extensible?  Or are there particular classes of applications where development can be greatly facilitated through the use of such techniques?

Comment: Have a look at Generics in C++.  Generic functions are pretty much the reason why templates exist.

Comment: My rude opinion is that it's very mixed and riddled with cons. Alexandrescu was always brilliant at pushing the limits of the languages he uses, highlighting their deficiencies, and continues to do so. But I really think the prevalence of things like policy class templates and ways to emulate variadic templates before they existed have been more of a hindrance than beneficial to our industry. It is hardly fun working with an enthusiastic developer who gets endlessly excited by the possibilities of meta template programming.

Comment: Some small things I think were invaluable, but they've made it to the standard quickly.. like a real static_assert. But especially policy class templates -- ugh, I hate them so much. They require so much boilerplate to use, and so difficult in terms of documentation. They're actually quite prevalent in my industry now (CG). For example, DreamWorks uses policy templates everywhere for OpenVDB and internally in their studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It basically lets you move errors and calculations from runtime to compile time. The most widely known example of this is generic containers, but you can get much more fancy. You can:

- Resolve virtual method pointers at compile time so you avoid the runtime overhead of a virtual method table.
- Use higher-kinded types (like functors and monads).
- Get a compile error if you try to write an invalid transition in a state machine.
- Automatically serialize something like JSON into a struct and vice versa without boilerplate conversion code.
- Validate a SQL query against the schema at compile time.
- Precompile a regex for more efficient searching.
- Enforce at compile time that an integer is in a certain range.

There is a lot you can move to compile time that most people have never considered, but the trade off is some weird-looking code and the craziest compiler errors you have ever seen.

Comment: As an anedcote, I once wanted to show a colleague a single boost compilation error. Had to email it because it hit our chat's 10k character limit. Hopefully concepts will clean this up.

Comment: I think compiler authors are finally starting to understand that their error messages are essentially their user interface, and are starting to accept that an error message that does not clearly state a) what is wrong and b) what the fix is, is a bug. "Better errors than the current state" was one of the goals of Clang, for example. Martin Odersky has even rejected useful new language features for Scala purely for the reason that he couldn't see a way of implementing them in the compiler with useful errors.

Comment: For all its awesomeness, the fact that the compile-time meta-language is a completely different language with completely different semantics and completely different syntax that was never meant to be a programming language in the first place is one of the biggest drawbacks of C++ compared to the approach in languages like Haskell (Template Haskell), Scala, or the entire Lisp family, where the runtime base language and the compile-time meta-language are one and the same.

Comment: I don’t like awesome code. I look code that looks like it’s written by a simpleton (who somehow manages to make no mistakes).

Comment: @JörgWMittag C++ is at least moving in the right direction, with more and more things `constexpr`